# Create an WPF Object with a dynamic size in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw a bar chart using grids in wpf.
Due to design issues I created a grid with 6 pre-defined rows, although more rows could be added if necessary.

As bars I'd like to use grids aswell (rectangles might also be possible, but i want to write text in them later, which was easier with grids so far)

All bars together next to each other would be 100% of the main grids size, while each bar on it's own is only a fracture (in %) of their combined value. Each bar is in its own row with a small gap in between.

I struggle to find a way to set the size of my bars to a percentage of the size of my main grid.

My code looks like this so far:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BarChart.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BarChart"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    namespace BarChart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// tbd
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            int counter = 1;
            int counter_c = 0;
            double[] values = { 656, 333, 812 };
            SolidColorBrush[] colors = { new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) };
            double maxValue = 0;
            foreach (double d in values)
            {
                maxValue = maxValue + d;
            }


        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (double d in values)
        {
            if(MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count > counter)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                RowDefinition gap = new RowDefinition();
                gap.Height = new GridLength(4);
                MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gap);

            }
            Grid gd = new Grid();
            gd.Width = d / maxValue * MainGrid.ActualWidth;
            gd.Background = colors[counter_c];
            Grid.SetRow(gd, counter);
            counter += 2;
            counter_c++;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(gd);
        }

    }
}
```

Currently neither height nor width (MainGrid.ActualWidth is currently 0) seem to be set to any usable value. I want my bar chart to scale dynamically with every window size (Ofc I'll later need a resize event for that, too. But first i need to be able to draw it once tho).

[image: I can't get the width in the code behind]

[image: i should look like this]

Comment: Perhaps an image of what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful. I fail to see why you can't just set `Height = "*"` if you want them to be a percentage.

Comment: You are talking about the rows? sure i could do that, but my current problem is, that i still struggle to get the width of my maingrid to create the my bars based on it. (Added some images)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused but it looks like you are trying to do all of this logic in the constructor (usually a bad practice). While in the constructor, this is before your controls have been visually created (which is why your `MainGrid.ActualWidth = 0`. Instead, hook up a `ContentRendered` event to your MainWindow. Then in the `MainWindow_ContentRendered` event, do your logic. During that time, your `MainGrid` will have the `ActualWidth` you are looking for.

Comment: For future questions, try to stick to one problem at a time. This question appears to be focused on getting the ActualWidth. If that is the case, then I can move my previous comment to an answer. If you then need assistance with the rows, you should ask a separate question focusing on that. This question originally had me confused on what the specific problem you were facing was because you started by saying "I struggle to find a way to set the size of my bars to a percentage of the size of my main grid."

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for. But now I need to initialize my Control from another Control call 'MainChartControl', which uses a DataTable as DependencyProperty to hand over values and colors for my bar chart. I previously tried to call a method with the same code as above each time the setter of my DependencyProperty was called and had the same Issues (probably because my MainGrid wasn't created at that point). Do you have any Idea how i can fix that, too ?

Comment: I am sorry for causing you confusion.  I wasn't quite sure what causes my bars not to draw at all , as I wasn't quite sure where my problem actually was. (could've been something wrong with the way I create my MainGrid, too, as it didn't have any width)

Comment: No worries, the misunderstanding was on my part. I'll move my comments to an answer with the addition of a usercontrol solution.

Comment: Added my comments as an answer, if you have another specific issue, I'd encourage you to post it as a separate question.

Comment: You might also get the results you want, by setting the ColumnDefinitions for single bar, like <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/><ColumnDefinition Width="80*">, which will create two columns with 20% and 80% of the total grid width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were trying to find the `MainGrid.ActualWidth` in the constructor, which would be before the control is visual created. To fix this, hook up a `ContentRendered` event and place the logic there.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        this.ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Logic here...
    }
```

`UserControls` don't have this event but you can use the `Loaded` event instead.

```
public YourUserControl()
    {
        this.Loaded += YourUserControl_Loaded;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void YourUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Logic here...
    }
```

These events will fire off after the controls are created and you will be able to see your `ActualWidth` property with the appropriate value.